# Как нажать на кнопку внутри Iframe или способы обхода?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть сайт, а внутри него iframe сайт с кнопками, которые мне нужно тыкныть что бы пройти тест.
Программно на основном сайте всё нажимается, но не внутри фрейма. Как можно реализовать?
Внутри фрейма сайт с другим доменом, если что.

Comment: Если другой домен, то никак, потому что иначе это была бы страшная дыра в безопасности (представьте, что если Stack Overflow открыл бы ваш аккаунт ВК в ифрейме и начал бы нажимать рассылку спама от вашего имени)

Comment: Если под программно подразумевается из кода родительского окна, то не получится. Наверное, можно при помощи расширения для браузера. Можно ещё при помощи какой-нибудь библиотеки для автоматизации работы с браузером вроде https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/ для Node.js.

Comment: Я использую cef